# Get all the properties in a class by using Reflection in C#

Tags: c#, class, reflection

I have a static class as following:

```
public static class Person
{
    public const string name = "james";
    public const string address = "address";
}
```

Now i want to get the class fields (name and address) from the other class by using Reflection to find the class name and get all its fields.

I tried :

```
 var allTypes = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a =>      a.FullName.StartsWith("TestReflection.Info"))
                        from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                        select type).ToArray();
```

first to get the class then to access to the class and find the class name and its properties but it always returns null when I tried to find a class file in the directory Info.

Could you suggest me the ideas of how can I get all the fields by using Reflection in C#? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to search for phrase `"Get all the properties in a class by using Reflection in C#"`?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy : I tried but as I commented in the answer below, I cannot specify the class Person in my main class, because it exists in other classes as well, same name with different values for name and address. What I can specify is the particular folder which contains a class Persons;

Comment: Sorry didn't get what is your problem. Anyway - question seams very misleading if your real problem is not getting properties of class, but searching for some specific instance of class

Comment: I think you are misusing classes. Why are you creating many classes with constant strings instead of creating an instance of a class, each time with different values as name and address?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy : Sorry if my english is confusing, I have 3 folders which are Room1, Room2, Room3, they all have the class Person with different name and address, one main class to retrieve the fields inside the class Person. e.g like : with typeof(Person) I just can specify the particular Person of Room 1, meanwhile I also have it in Room 2 and 3